# Como calcular distancia entre dos puntos en sql server

Tags: sql

Quisiera obtener la distancia entre dos puntos en sql server, el problema que tenia anteriormente, es que tenia los datos latitud y longitud en una sola columna, lo cual ya logre resolver ese problema mediante un split, ahora quisiera saber como puedo usar el resultado para poder calcular la distancia entre dos puntos.

```
    SELECT TOP 10 [LDPID],[LatLon], SUBSTRING(LatLon, 1,9) AS LATITUD, SUBSTRING(LatLon, 11,19) AS LONGITUD FROM LDP
```

este es mi resultado del split

[image: result]

ahora quisiera calcular la distancia entre los dos puntos,me he guiado de este articulo pero no encuentro la manera de usar los resultados para poder calcular la distancia.
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/18/sql-server-tips-from-the-sql-joes-2-pros-development-series-geography-data-type-calculating-distance-between-two-points-on-the-earth-day-18-of-35/

Comment: Hola, quieres calcular la distancia entre 2 puntos dentro tu consulta SQL? no sería mejor en el lenguaje en el que estas programando tu proyecto?

Comment: @the-breaker dices en la aplicacion, es una buena opcion, pero ahora quiero hacerlo en sql

Comment: bien, pero entre cuales puntos quieres calcular la distancia? necesitas 2 puntos o mejor no podrías colocar como quieres que se vea el resultado?

Comment: @the-breaker entre el punto 1 o 2, no importa el orden solo quiero calcular la distancia entre dos registros, ejemplo `LDPID 3` ENTRE `LDPID 1201`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder calcular correctamente la distancia entre dos puntos en sql server y tener un margen minimo de error se realiza lo siguiente.

```
  --split para dos registros con la misma cantidad de numero
SELECT TOP 10 [LDPID], [LockID] ,[LockNumber],[LatLon], SUBSTRING(LatLon, 1,8) AS LATITUD, SUBSTRING(LatLon, 10,19) AS LONGITUD FROM LDP 

     --agregamos nueva columa a la base de datos
   alter table LDP add geoloc GEOGRAPHY null
      -- actualizamos la columa  geoloc

update LDP SET [geoloc] = GEOGRAPHY::Point(SUBSTRING(LatLon, 1,8) , SUBSTRING(LatLon, 10,19) , 4326) where LDPID = 1419


--declaramos las variables
declare @LAT GEOGRAPHY;
declare @LONG GEOGRAPHY;

select @LAT = [geoloc] FROM LDP where LDPID = 1201
select @LONG = [geoloc] FROM LDP where LDPID = 1419


select @LAT.STDistance(@LONG) as [Distance in Meters],
    @LAT.STDistance(@LONG)/ 1000 as [Distance in KM]
```

Answer (score 1):

para obtener la distancia entre 2 puntos con una consulta SQL se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
    select SQRT(POWER(CONVERT(decimal(9,6), T2.LATITUD)-CONVERT(decimal(9,6), T1.LATITUD),2)+POWER(CONVERT(decimal(9,6), T2.LONGITUD)-CONVERT(decimal(9,6), T1.LONGITUD),2)) as distancia
from 
(SELECT [LDPID],[LatLon], SUBSTRING(LatLon, 1,9) AS LATITUD, SUBSTRING(LatLon, 11,19) AS LONGITUD 
FROM LDP) as T1, 
(SELECT [LDPID],[LatLon], SUBSTRING(LatLon, 1,9) AS LATITUD, SUBSTRING(LatLon, 11,19) AS LONGITUD 
FROM LDP) as T2
where T1.LDPID=3 and T2.LDPID=1201
```

Esta consulta hallara la distancia entre los puntos 3 y 1201.
En la primera linea se emplea la formula matemática para hallar la distancia entre 2 puntos. Indícame si te funciona.

Comment: lo acabo de probar pero me marca un error `Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 56 The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator`

Comment: mmm, esta tomando la latitud y longitud como cadenas, dame un momento

Comment: @Daniel, he modificado la consulta para convertir los varchar en decimales, ahora ya debería correr

Comment: me marca el error `Error converting data type varchar to float.` ya cambie el decimal por float pero me sigue marcando el mismo error

Comment: @Daniel, ya lo vi, es por que en la latitud del punto 2 hay una coma al final del numero `33.022229,` puedes cambiarle el `SUBSTRING(LatLon, 1,9)` a `SUBSTRING(LatLon, 1,8)`

Comment: gracias, me funciono tu respuesta

Comment: de nada pero ten cuidado, estas perdiendo un dígito en las longitudes, saludos

Comment: es cierto tienes razon, me podrias explicar la logica que usaste al medir la distancia, el resultado es en metros o kilometros?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76038/discussion-between-the-breaker-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este sp: (ojo con el separador de unidades y decimales. Debe ser el punto, aunque la función inferior, hace el replace)

```
create procedure SP_DistanciaEntrePuntos(
@LatP1 nvarchar(20), @LonP1 nvarchar(20),
@LatP2 nvarchar(20), @LonP2 nvarchar(20)
)
as

declare @P1 as GEOGRAPHY
SET @P1 = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@LatP1 , @LonP1 , 4326)
SELECT  @P1.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(@LatP2, @LonP2 , 4326)) /1000 AS km 

go

--de burgos a madrid:

SP_DistanciaEntrePuntos '42.361895141824014','-3.6797329410','40.41470221053658','-3.666900527647'
```

--- tambien puedes usar esta función de similar código

```
alter function FN_DistanciaEntrePuntos(
@LatP1 nvarchar(20), @LonP1 nvarchar(20),
@LatP2 nvarchar(20), @LonP2 nvarchar(20)
)
returns numeric(11,3)
as
begin
set @LatP1 = replace(@LatP1,',','.')
set @LonP1 = replace(@LonP1,',','.')
set @LatP2 = replace(@LatP2,',','.')
set @LonP2 = replace(@LonP2,',','.')
declare @P1 as GEOGRAPHY
SET @P1 = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@LatP1 , @LonP1 , 4326)
return @P1.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(@LatP2, @LonP2 , 4326)) /1000 
end
```